# How is it safe for several git users to use the same remote repo?

Tags: git

I'm wondering how it could be safe for several git users to use the same remote repo, with no git server software.  Aren't there potential corruption issues if several users are pushing and fetching at the same time, possibly even pushing the same commits?

Comment: Git will throw an error if you try to push a branch that is behind the HEAD - you'll be forced to pull in the latest changes. Ideally the users should fork the repo and create pull requests back to the main repo

Comment: Duplicate question, but it's safe because it's using a lock file.

Answer (score 0):

**If you're using a fileshare system:**

Git will copy your commits to a temp folder and then apply the necessary locks to ensure the operation is atomic.

This question has been answered on [ServerFault](https://serverfault.com/a/482414).

**If you're using a server such as Github:**

These server makes sure these operations are atomic.

However, if you're pushing several branches at a time, the server may accept some and reject other branches because they've been updated meanwhile. But the server will never accept half of a commit.

How do they guarantee atomicity? You'll have to ask a GitHub dev, for example.

Comment: What server?  I am not using any server.  See the question... I am just setting a fileshare as a remote

Comment: @JoelFan "a remote repo" entails a remote server.

Comment: Not true... you can set a remote that is just a file:://

Comment: Here is my remote:  $ git remote -v
origin  file://F:\Git\MyProj (fetch)
origin  file://F:\Git\MyProj (push)

Comment: @JoelFan (responding to your updated comment) Well, that's a very important detail and you should have mentioned it on your question. The answer is still - it's safe. Git will put your commits in a local folder before moving them to the actual repo, and lock accordingly.

Comment: You can't lock over ssh.  It could start pushing and before it's done, another user starts pushing or fetching

Comment: @JoelFan What does the transport protocol have to do with this? I can have an application that accepts many requests concurrently, put everything into temp folders, and them move then to the actual folder one at a time. It doesn't matter how the data was transmitted.

Comment: But ssh does not know anything about git... it just accepts file transfers

Comment: @JoelFan But the files don't go straight from the network cable into git's main database. They have to go through git first. Ssh doesn't know what a lock is, but git does. I'm sorry if I'm misunderstanding your question, but I really don't see any issue.

Comment: There is no git running on the server.  All that's running on the server is ssh or maybe even just the OS (if it's a fileshare remote)

Comment: @JoelFan Fair enough - Consider this then: it seems entirely possible that the client (on your computer) may be controlling the mechanism, by creating a .lock file as Don Branson mentioned. Does that seem plausible?

Comment: When you're going over ssh, git will run on the server side. It's not running as a daemon, but in response to your push.

Comment: It would transfer the .lock file over ssh?

Comment: Once you push, the SHA of the head is different, and no one else can do a push until they pull your change. When they pull your change, it will merge your code with theirs, and they must resolve any conflicts before they push.

Comment: It doesn't transfer the lock file over ssh, the git process will create it on the server side.

Comment: @DonBranson Thank you for your input. I knew that it was done with locks, but you seem to know a lot more about its internals.

Comment: @dcastro Not a whole lot, but Google knows ;).

Answer (score -1):

Git solves this issue through branches. Basically, you make your own copy of the repo, and work on that. When you want to submit your changes to the main branch, you send the creator a pull request. Here's a link to GitHub's page on [pull requests](https://help.github.com/articles/using-pull-requests).

Now, if two different branches have made changes to the same part, and then someone attempts to merge them together, you get a merge conflict. Git basically stops everything and gives you any conflicting files, with the changes inside a conflict-marked area. You then have to resolve any conflict areas with whichever set of changes you want to keep. Note that, for each conflict, you can go with either branch's change, or even make a new one. You can read more about merge conflicts [here](https://help.github.com/articles/resolving-merge-conflicts).

You can also use Google or search GitHub for more about this. There's instructions on how to do this sort of thing over command line as well.

Comment: I don't want to use pull requests... I just want every developer to be able to push commits to the same remote repo

Comment: So you mean if everyone pushes to a single (i.e. the master) branch? Then if a user doesn't have the most recent changes, it won't allow them to push commits to the branch. edit: It also might have them make their own branch if this occurs.

Comment: what if many users, all of which have the most recent changes, are pushing at once, and while the pushes are in progress, others are fetching?

Comment: I'm not 100% sure how the internals work, but it would probably prioritize the pushes over the fetches. As for pushes then, it might be just luck of the draw over who is able to push and who gets rejected. Also, instead of outright rejecting a push, it might automatically fork and have them push into their own branch, leaving everyone to resolve branch merge conflicts.

Comment: There is no server software to "prioritize" anything... everyone is reading and writing to a fileshare or ssh

Comment: Then you will be using branches and branch merging. You don't necessarily need pull requests to use branches.

Comment: So are you saying it's not safe (and there will be corruption) if we don't use branching and merging?

Comment: Branching has nothing to do with this.

Comment: Branching and merging is generally the safest way to go when there are multiple developers working on the same code at the same time, yes. I don't know how likely your scenario is (half are pushing, and half are fetching, all at the same time), but branches are a solution to this.

Comment: Branches are not the answer to this issue. Git is designed to deal with this transparently to the user. Branches are great for many things, but have nothing to do with this issue. This answer is just dead wrong.